# Grabbing all the "names" from a tree structure

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

There are endless amount of tree questions on here, but for me, it would be nice if someone could help me with this specific question.  I took a "mock interview" for my boot camp and this was a question.  I did not have a good way to approach it..

```
const people = {
    name: "Robin",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Alberto",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Quinn",
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: "Conner",
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Lila",
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Charlie",
            children: []
        }
    ]
}

// Write a function called getNames that returns a string "Robin, Alberto, Quinn, Conner, Lila, Charlie
```

It can be a little overwhelming when you're trying to learn this stuff, especially when you're sifting through a multitude of questions that have different angles to solving them.  So, help on this particular one would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `function getNames() { return "Robin, Alberto, Quinn, Conner, Lila, Charlie" }` :-P

Comment: haha I wonder what the instructor would have done if I did that with a straight face.   Didn't say a word, typed it out real quick and yelled done :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `reduce` method with recursive approach where you `concat` the output of reduce to initial `name` string.f

```js
const people = {"name":"Robin","children":[{"name":"Alberto","children":[{"name":"Quinn","children":[{"name":"Conner","children":[]},{"name":"Lila","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Charlie","children":[]}]}

function getNames(data, name = "") {
    return data.name + (data.children ?
      data.children.reduce((r, e) => {
        return r + ", " + getNames(e)
      }, "") : "")
}

console.log(getNames(people))
```

Another recursive solution is to use `map` and `flatten` methods where you can pick all names and then also turn them to string by using `join` method.

```js
const people = {"name":"Robin","children":[{"name":"Alberto","children":[{"name":"Quinn","children":[{"name":"Conner","children":[]},{"name":"Lila","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Charlie","children":[]}]}


function getString({ name, children }) {
  return [name, ...children.map(getString).flat()].join(', ')
}

const result = getString(people)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for the help.  I'll definitely go through and study this!

Comment: `reduce`->`concat` is generalized to `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just use recursion.

```js
const people = { name: "Robin", children: [ { name: "Alberto", children: [ { name: "Quinn", children: [ { name: "Conner", children: [] }, { name: "Lila", children: [] } ] } ] }, { name: "Charlie", } ]};

function getNames(tree) {
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    names.push(tree[i].name)
    if (tree[i].children) {
      names = names.concat(getNames(tree[i].children))
    }
  }
  return names;
}
var names = getNames([people]);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Just heads-up - the function right now doesn't work. It's only because it expects an array and "people" is actually an object. When calling it with an array (e.g. `getNames( [ people ] )`) it does work. I've left it, though, so you can decide whether to do that to fix it or change the logic inside.

Comment: I don't really know why `people` is not an array. To be honest, it seems wrong to me but that was the sample data OP had, so I just left it. I didn't want to "mess" with your answer, so I deferred to you to make the call of how to do it. In real code, if I'm somehow getting that sort of data, I'd be perfectly OK with wrapping it in an array to pass to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive data structures can be easily transformed using the new [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const people =
  { name: "Robin", children: [ { name: "Alberto", children: [ { name: "Quinn", children: [ { name: "Conner", children: [] }, { name: "Lila", children: [] } ] } ] }, { name: "Charlie", } ]};

const getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) =>
  [ name, ...children.flatMap(getNames) ]
  
console.log(getNames(people))
// [ "Robin", "Alberto", "Quinn", "Conner", "Lila", "Charlie" ]
```

If your environment doesn't define it, you can write your own `flatMap`

```js
const flatMap = (f, xs = [], context = null) =>
  xs.reduce
    ( (acc, x, i) =>
        acc.concat (f.call (context, x, i, xs))
    , []
    )

const people =
  { name: "Robin", children: [ { name: "Alberto", children: [ { name: "Quinn", children: [ { name: "Conner", children: [] }, { name: "Lila", children: [] } ] } ] }, { name: "Charlie", } ]};

const getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) =>
  [ name, ...flatMap (getNames, children) ]
  
console.log(getNames(people))
// [ "Robin", "Alberto", "Quinn", "Conner", "Lila", "Charlie" ]
```

`flatMap` is supported in Node 11, but no longer included in `babel-polyfill` as of Babel 7, where it now has to be [manually imported](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration)

```
// Node 10 or Babel 7
import 'core-js/fn/array/flat-map'
```

Of you can polyfill it manually

```js
// manual polyfill
Array.prototype.flatMap =
  function (f, context = null) {
    return this.reduce
      ( (acc, x, i) => 
          acc.concat (f.call (context, x, i, this))
      , []
      )
  }

const people =
  { name: "Robin", children: [ { name: "Alberto", children: [ { name: "Quinn", children: [ { name: "Conner", children: [] }, { name: "Lila", children: [] } ] } ] }, { name: "Charlie", } ]};

const getNames = ({ name, children = [] }) =>
  [ name, ...children.flatMap(getNames) ]
  
console.log(getNames(people))
// [ "Robin", "Alberto", "Quinn", "Conner", "Lila", "Charlie" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Are you the king of recursion/trees?!  I have seen you in multiple threads.  I'm honored you commented on mine :D.  Also, really quick!  My environment is now allowing that first example. How do I display the names in the second?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :D – I hope my update helps